# Blog on Django, querysets for fetch logged in user's posts

Tags: python, django

I'm building a blog on Django and know i have to make a personal page for see all the posts published by the user we're logged in now.
I'm using some querysets so.
Her my code

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Here my forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Post

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2','user_permissions','is_staff','date_joined']

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'author']
```

And that's the view which is gonna filter the posts in base of the logged user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone

from .forms import CreateUserForm
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

def user_data(request, pk):
   user_data = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
   posts = user_data.post_set.filter(author=user_data)
   context = {'user_data':user_data, 'posts':posts}
   return render(request, 'account/user_data.html', context)




#So it returns me just the user data like name, email or date_joined but not his posts
```

Comment: can you add your template code please?

Comment: in addition, post your url.py file as well

Comment: add your template as well, most probably you are displaying the posts data. also ```user_data.post_set.all()``` will show all the posts for that specific user, no need to filter there.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you posts of logged in users from your view

```
def user_data(request, pk):
   posts=Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
   context = {'posts':posts}
   return render(request, 'account/user_data.html', context)
```

Comment: OP already gets the posts properly in this line `posts = user_data.post_set.filter(author=user_data)`...

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat the idea was to reduce redundant lines of codes.